# 1 wordpress installation 2 domains

Tags: wordpress, url, dns

I have one installation of wordpress at domain1.co.uk.

I have another domain (domain2.com) and I have changed the A record so that it now points to the installation at domain1.co.uk whist keeping the domain2.com URL.

My issue is when I click any links within the wordpress site the URL changes to domain1.co.uk/pagename and does not retain the .com.  I know the wordpress site address is setup to domain1.co.uk at the moment but I would like to be able to retain the domain2.com when visited from domain2.com throughout the site.

Is that possible?

Any help will be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either have to use wpmu somehow (wordpress multisite has been integrated into wordpress) or you can enable the wordpress (multisite feature)[http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network].

It is as easy as:

```
// wp-config.php
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

Then going to the network setup tool, adding some more lines to the config, adding some lines to the htaccess, and creating an upload directory.